# How to modify a SSH configuration file using a puppet module

Tags: ssh, configuration, puppet

I am trying to modify a SSH configuration file to remove the `arcfour`, `arcfour 128` and `arcfour 256` algorithms in the `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` on 186 linux servers using puppet. Basically, I am doing a find and replace to remove those three algorithm types in the `sshd_config` file.  I created a module called `SSH_Test` and am wondering what my next steps would be. I think I can use these resources, but I am unsure where to put them, and I am not sure if they are right

```
file_line { 'Ciphers':
  path  => '/etc/ssh/sshd_config',
  line  => 'arcfour, arcfour128, arcfour256',
  match => '',
}
```

New configuration from below comment

```
node default { 
  file { '/etc/motd':
    owner => 'root',
    group => 'root',
    mode => '0644',
    content => "\nAll hail the knife crab\n"
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for responding I really appreciate the help I'm circling back and trying to rebuild the puppet master and agents as they were on a older version and I've built out 3 new servers 2 agents and 1 master. I've put puppet 4.7 on all  I've made a very simple site.pp file with the follow. My problem is when I try to to puppet agent -test on my agents i get a cannot parse environment production 500 error any ideas?

node default { 
  file { '/etc/motd':
 owner => 'root',
 group => 'root',
mode => '0644',
content => "\nAll hail the knife crab\n"
}

}

Comment: I will try the more advanced configuration below as soon as I am able as I am very new to puppet and trying to figure things out as a I go and any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Turns out i just needed to add some 755 permission to the manifest directory my site.pp is working now and I will attempt to deal with ssh configuration now

Answer (score 1):

Following the documentation for `file_line` provided here: https://forge.puppet.com/puppetlabs/stdlib/types

we have the following resource:

```
file_line { 'Ciphers':
  ensure            => absent,
  path              => '/etc/ssh/sshd_config',
  match             => '.*arcfour.*',
  multiple          => true,
  match_for_absence => true,
}
```

`ensure` to remove the line, `path` for the specified file, `match` for the lines to match with a regexp, `multiple` because you want this to act on multiple lines in a file, and `match_for_absence` so that the lines are removed when matched.

If you are using Puppet >= 4.0, or 3.8 with the future parser, then this can be made more precise and cleaner with a lambda. Let me know if you are.